# formfield_for_foreignkey seems to do nothing

Tags: django, django-admin

I am following the scheme shown here and in various other places: https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/filter_fk_dropdown.html

My code looks like this:

```
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    #...

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        groups = [group.name for group in request.user.groups.all()]
        if 'principal' in groups:
            school = request.user.principal.school
            if db_field == "room":
                kwargs['queryset'] = Room.objects.filter(school=school)
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

    list_display = ('surname','givennames', 'room')
    list_filter = ('room',)
```

I have verified that the code is invoked and *school* is set correctly, but no filtering on the selector is happening. That is, I can see all the *room* instances regardless of their respective value for *school*.

Once deployed in the real world, the list will show far too many items, most that the user will not want to and should not see. But the filtering is not happening. Any ideas what I've missed?

Is it relevant that *school* itself is a foreign key to *room*? That has worked fine in other filters

Also I would like similar filtering on the list_filter on the select view, but this code isn't even invoked there. Advice much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @mt_ this is a niche one, so I will ask some questions before posting an aswer today. Could you add `print(groups)` and `print(type(groups))` to the `formfield_for_foreignkey` method for me, so we can start to debug what groups is, and whether we are getting into the first `if` statement...I've added this to your method so there's no confusion (let me know if this fails because you might be using Python 2.7 where the variable inside the `print` call is not wrapped ()

Comment: Update: if db_field == "room" is never true. db_field has type <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: room>
and its string repesentation is "input.Student.room"

I suddenly realize I was stupid to call an app "input", but that doesn't seem to be the problem. The models I was using compare db_field to a string...

Comment: What’s happens if you use Rooms.objects.all().filter(school=school) ?

Comment: That is not the problem; the principal conditional is happening. The match to db_field is not. But for what it's worth ['principal'] and <class 'list'> .

Comment: That's not the problem either. The match 
    db_field == Student.room
is never satisfied. So nothing will happen if I modify the filter.

Comment: No worries. Just narrowing things down. So when you print db_field what is the output...and what is its type if it exists?

Comment: Aargh another dumb question! if db_field.name == 'room'

I forgot .name !

Comment: Not dumb at all mt_ - these things are very niche and often overlooked in documentation! :)

Answer (score 2):

change the db_field checking to this:

```
 if db_field.name == "room":
```

Answer (score 0):

following the scheme shown here and in various other places: https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/filter_fk_dropdown.html

My repaired code looks like this:

```
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

#...

def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    groups = [group.name for group in request.user.groups.all()]
    if 'principal' in groups:
        school = request.user.principal.school
        if db_field.name == "room": # This was the error; 
                                    # nothing wrong with the example; 
                                    # I just bobbled the retranscription
            kwargs['queryset'] = Room.objects.filter(school=school)
    return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

list_display = ('surname','givennames', 'room')
list_filter = ('room',)
```